# How to change inet to run expo in docker-Compose

Tags: docker, react-native, docker-compose, expo

When iam using `exp build:android` command to make apk in docker-compose it showing following error.

```
Building iOS bundle
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
```

i also use

```
ports:
 - "19001:19001"
 - "19000:19000"
```

My docker **inet** is **172.17.0.1**

so how to change the inet to run expo in docker-compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this we had to remove `.expo` folder and then run `exp build:android`